# How do I find XML nodes which don't contain an attribute using XPath?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I'm using XPath in VB.net with the following XML:

```
<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title>English-French Dictionary</title>
  <price>29.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

According to [this guide](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), it's easy to get a list of nodes which have a particular attributes.

> //title[@lang]
>   Selects all the title elements that have an attribute
>   named lang

But how do you get the list of nodes which *don't* have a particular attribute? (e.g. The third book above, which has no `lang` attribute.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
//title[not(@lang)]
```